# How to get both Hlines and Vlines in the vizualisation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

one of the line appears in the vizualisation

```
%matplotlib

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
def grid_sncf_generation_mitry():
    plt.figure(figsize=(50,100))


    # general var
    hcoord = np.arange(0,1,23)


    # Adding the time zone

    # J'ai restreint la plage horaire

    v2=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T03:30')
    v1=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T05:40')

    # Adding Stations V5 / V3 / SAS5 / SAS3

    plt.hlines("GA",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
    plt.hlines("SAS3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
    plt.hlines("SAS5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
    plt.hlines("V3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
    plt.hlines("V5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")

    #plt.vlines(hcoord,0,4)

    # id station
    plt.ylabel("MITRY")

    # Time axis
    # Adding Hours
    myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())

    # Adding Minutes
    myFmt2 = mdates.DateFormatter('%M')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(myFmt2)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]))


    # Minimisize the police of minutes
    for tick in plt.gca().xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
        tick.label.set_fontsize(6)

    # comment détecter les heurs ?



    # comment détecter les 30's ?

    plt.show()
    return plt
```

I want to get both hlines and vlines in the visualisation

Comment: Your code doesn't have any uncommented calls to `plt.vlines`. Specifically what goes wrong when you try that?

Comment: what goes wrong is when i remove the # from plt.vlines(hcoord,0,4) i get only a vertical line and the horizontal ones go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from mixing datetime units and non-datetime values.

When you run your code while uncommenting `plt.vlines(hcoord,0,4)`, you should receive an Exception:

```
fig = plt.figure()
hcoord = np.arange(0,1,23)
v2=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T03:30')
v1=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T05:40')

# Adding Stations V5 / V3 / SAS5 / SAS3

plt.hlines("GA",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("SAS3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("SAS5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("V3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("V5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")

plt.vlines(hcoord,0,4)
plt.show()
```

> ValueError: view limit minimum -36865.76180555556 is less than 1 and
>   is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a
>   non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

While replacing `hcoord` with a datetime value works as expected:

```
fig = plt.figure()
hcoord = np.arange(0,1,23)
v2=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T03:30')
v1=np.datetime64('2019-09-13T05:40')

# Adding Stations V5 / V3 / SAS5 / SAS3

plt.hlines("GA",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("SAS3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("SAS5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("V3",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")
plt.hlines("V5",v1,v2,"grey","dotted")

plt.vlines(v2,0,4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are trying to plot with `hccord = np.arange(0,1,23)`, since this instruction returns `[0]`. You'll have to figure out how to generate the right `hcoord` array in datetime units to get the plot that you are expecting.

Comment: Diziet, you're the man ! ty :D
You fixed what i wanted to make.
i didn't knew what hcoord takes as values.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark on the left to close the topic